# why does the pip installs the packages only from the cache?

Tags: python, caching, pip

I had few pip packages installed from my previous projects and i uninstalled all the packages from my virtual environment but now when i want to install the fresh packages than pip doesn't even look for it in the internet, it just keeps deriving the packages from the cache of same version. 
It works when i delete the pip folder from AppData but again the same cache derives on the next installation for the another project too.
Please any help will be highly appreciated. The operating system i am using is Windows 10. Thank you.

Comment: Just to make to make it clear, are you calling something like `pip install SomeProject==1.2.3` or more like `pip install SomeProject`?

Comment: This is not the expected behavior of pip, it's only supposed to use the cache when the version in PyPI is identical. Do you have anything configured in %HOME%\pip\pip.ini ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the [`--no-cache-dir` option] to disable pip's cache (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching).